# Can I cancel out of a palette choice?

Tags: skullgirls

In two player/etc I'll often accidentally press X to select my character, when to pick an explicit palette from a list you need to press Start (otherwise a palette is mapped to whatever button you press and you get that one). Is there any way to cancel out of this palette choice so I can choose again? If I press circle (cancel in PS3 controls) it just continues anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing Select (PS3, probably the same on 360) will act as "cancel" anywhere in the Character Select screen. This lets you cancel out of a palette, character or assist choice.